# I need a little help on iOS with parse.com (PFObject)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject

I have two classes on Parse.com which are :

First User class: username,password,email,and userTitle.

Second Messages class: senderName, file, fileType, senderTitle, senderId, recipientIds.

My code :

```
        PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];
        [message setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
        [message setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
        [message setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
        [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
        [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
        [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {…..
```

I can't set "userTitle" from class User to "senderTitle" in class Messages by above method, is there anyone there have idea how to do so? thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PFUser` is just a subclass of `PFObject`, which is a implements a Dictionary interface, so you can use `[PFUser currentUser][@"userTitle"]` just as you could use `message[@"file"]`.

Also, if `senderId` is a reference type column you can just say `message[@"senderId"]=[PFUser currentUser];` - The Parse framework will resolve the object Id for you.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! ;-) I should practice more ;)